# How do I migrate node entity references?

Tags: 8, entities, migrations

I would like to migrate node entity references from D7 to D8. In my D7 application, many nodes are related to other with the "entity reference" system. But related nodes could belong to many node types like "article", "page", "news", and so on.

I tried to use "entity_lookup" plugin, but this does not work (SQL error):

```
field_related_content:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_related_content
    process:
        target_id:
            plugin: entity_lookup
            no_stub: true
            entity_type: node
            bundle_key: type
            bundle:
              - presse
              - news
              - page
            value_key: nid
```

SQL Error is:

```
In Connection.php line 701:
                                                                                                                                                                                   
  SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens: SELECT base_table.vid AS vid, base_table.nid AS nid                        
  FROM                                                                                                                                                                             
  {node} base_table                                                                                                                                                                
  INNER JOIN {node_field_data} node_field_data ON node_field_data.nid = base_table.nid                                                                                             
  WHERE (node_field_data.nid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (node_field_data.type = :db_condition_placeholder_1:db_condition_placeholder_2:db_condition_placeholder_3); Array  
  (                                                                                                                                                                                
      [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =>                                                                                                                                             
      [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => presse                                                                                                                                      
      [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => news                                                                                                                                        
      [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => page                                                                                                                                        
  )
```

Someone has an idea?

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I added the SQL error in my question :)

Comment: `bundle` must be a string, not an array. You cannot lookup multiple bundles at the same time, you must specify exactly one bundle.

Comment: I understood the error, but I don't know how to import this field values. Indeed, field_related_content contents more than one entity reference and those entity reference could belong to different content type. Is there another way to proceed?

Comment: Your source must provide the bundle and in the process section you must provide the bundle by referencing the source field.

Comment: I would like not to use bundle, but only node ID. Is that possible?